# How to print multiple strings from a function in Java?

Tags: java, function, variables

I am very new to learning Java, so I tried making a very basic program where I have 2 text documents, one filled with 2,000 first names and the other having 1,000 last names. The program will take a random line from each and print it out as one line. However, I am getting into trouble when trying to do so. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

  private static Random first = new Random();
  private static Random second = new Random();
  private static int firstnumber = 0;
  private static int secondnumber = 0;
  private static String line1 = " ";
  private static String line2 = " ";

  public static void generateAnswers(){
      
      firstnumber = first.nextInt(999);
      firstnumber += 1;
      try{
        String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Firstnames.txt")).get(firstnumber);
      } 
      catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
      }

      secondnumber = second.nextInt(999);
      secondnumber += 1;
      try{
        String line2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Lastnames.txt")).get(secondnumber);
      }
      catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
      }
      System.out.println(line1 + " " + line2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      generateAnswers();
  }

}
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Basically, you are printing String line2 = " "; and String line1=" "   because you have defined another String line2 and line1 inside your try and catch. So they are not assigned to any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was because your static variables like `line1` and `line2` were not being assigned with a value. Your problem lays in this line. You have created another String and not assigned your static with a new value

```
String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Firstnames.txt")).get(firstnumber);
```

Change

```
String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Firstnames.txt")).get(firstnumber);
```

With

```
line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Firstnames.txt")).get(firstnumber);
```

And

```
String line2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Lastnames.txt")).get(secondnumber);
```

With

```
 line2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Lastnames.txt")).get(secondnumber);
```